# Deserialize OData type JSON with child elements using RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, odata, restsharp

So I have this Json OData Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:7548/DynamicsNAV110/api/beta/$metadata#companies(9b562fdb-5071-4aef-8bf6-d7aa6fd0b472)/salesOrders",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzQ0O2R4VUFBQUo3LzFBQVZnQXhBRGdBTFFBd0FEQUFNQUF3QURrQUFBQUFBQT09Nzs4MTAwMDQyMDsn\"",
            "id": "ae5dddef-397b-4fda-bfc2-7fb6490b295d",
            "number": "PV18-00009",
            "customerNumber": "10780",
            "billingPostalAddress": {
                "street": "HONDURAS N'.43",
                "city": "AGUIMES",
                "state": "LAS PALMAS",
                "countryLetterCode": "ES",
                "postalCode": "35260"
            },
            "salesOrderLines@odata.context": "http://localhost:7548/DynamicsNAV110/api/beta/$metadata#companies(9b562fdb-5071-4aef-8bf6-d7aa6fd0b472)/salesOrders(ae5dddef-397b-4fda-bfc2-7fb6490b295d)/salesOrderLines",
            "salesOrderLines": [
                {
                    "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzQwO1pCVUFBQUNSNzkxZHJuczUyaysvd24rMlNRc3BYUUNIRUNjQUFBQUExOzAwOyc=\"",
                    "documentId": "ae5dddef-397b-4fda-bfc2-7fb6490b295d",
                    "sequence": 10000,
                    "itemId": "fb326b66-26be-4e38-a53f-301da19f445b",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "lineDetails": {
                        "number": "0000000",
                        "displayName": "REMATE BLANCO EXTERNO 90"
                    },
                    "unitOfMeasure": {
                        "code": "UDS",
                        "displayName": "Unidades",
                        "symbol": null,
                        "unitConversion": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize this with RestSharp, so I have this 2 classes:

```
public class SalesOrder
        {
            public string number { get; set; }
            public SalesOrderLine[] salesOrderLines { get; set; }
        }

        public class SalesOrderLine
        {
            public string itemId { get; set; }
        }
```

And also this custom Wrapper:

```
public class ODataCollectionWrapper<T> where T : class
        {
            public IEnumerable<T> Value { get; set; }
        }
```

This is my request:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:7548/DynamicsNAV110/api/beta/companies%289b562fdb-5071-4aef-8bf6-d7aa6fd0b472%29/salesOrders?$filter=number%20eq%20%27PV18-00009%27&$expand=salesOrderLines");
            client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute<ODataCollectionWrapper<SalesOrder>>(request);
```

So in the debugger I can see that I correctly have the parent element in response.Data.Value.number, but the child SalesOrderLines element is not loading.

Any ideas on how can I serialize this correctly?

Comment: Wouldn't your access be `response.Data.Value[0].number` and subsequently `response.Data.Value[0].salesOrderLines[0].itemId ` ....?

Comment: It's not there. Actually if I write response.Data in code it wont compile.. I can see in debugger only. salesOrderLines is null